# Phpmailer working locally, but not working on server. Getting error: escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpmailer

```php
$mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
$mail->Username = '********@gmail.com';   
$mail->Password = '********';       
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';      
$mail->Port     = 587;
```

When I am using IsSmtp() message does not send it will stop on send.
When I remove IsSmtp() mail send properly but it gives the following error:

> escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: Sounds like your hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP, which is very common. Refer to the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide and your ISP’s docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just add $mail->isSMTP();  That will avoid using escapeshellcmd().

Comment: How does this cover *When I am using IsSmtp() message does not send it will stop on send*